# Como pular a linha na escrita dos arquivos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bom, basicamente, eu preciso pular uma linha, após determinada escrita.

```
insira o código aqui
print("+---------------------+")
print("|DEMONSTRAÇÃO DA LINHA|")
print("+---------------------+")

print()

arqTeste = open("ArquivoTeste.txt", "w")



arqTeste.write("Python")

#Tentativa de Pular linha
arqTeste.write("")

arqTeste.write("Python 3")
arqTeste.close()
```

Bom, uma outra dúvida, como eu posso usar dois objetos na escrita de um arquivo?
Por exemplo:

```
insira o código aqui
nome = "Ana"
idade = "20"

arqTest2 = open("arqTest2.txt", "w")

#É essa a minha outra dúvida, não sei como fazer isso!
arqTest2.write("Nome =", nome)
arqTest2.write("Idade =", idade)

arqTest2.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para saltares uma linha ao escrever num ficheiro fazes:

```
...
#Tentativa de Pular linha
arqTeste.write("\n")
...
```

Para concatenares variáveis a uma string podes fazer assim:

```
...
#É essa a minha outra dúvida, não sei como fazer isso!
arqTest2.write("Nome = {}".format(nome))
arqTest2.write("Idade = {}".format(idade))
...
```

Apesar de existirem [mais maneiras](https://pyformat.info/), esta é a mais "versátil"/aconselhada de momento

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou amigo, mas, não tem outras formas de fazer essas duas coisas(por questão de curiosidade mesmo, rsrs)?

Comment: QUanto à primeira tenho quase a certeza que não, quanto à segunda existem mais ex: `arqTest2.write("Idade = " +str(idade))` , mas aconselho a usar `format`. @Kappa, se ajudei marca sff a resposta como aceite, por baixo das setas cima/baixo à esquerda da resposta

Comment: Obrigado, tirou todas minhas dúvidas!!

Comment: @Kappa de nada, ainda bem que resolveste

Answer (score 0):

Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, caso não seja isto, me desculpe, amigo!
Eu tenho um programa de Entradas e Saídas, da qual imprimo o BD em ".txt"
Aqui está uma ideia do projeto: (Em VB)

```
 Private Sub btListarValores_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btListarValores.Click
    Try
        Dim ENTRA(5) As String
        Dim itm As ListViewItem
        ENTRA(0) = TextDesc.Text
        ENTRA(1) = TextMes.Text
        ENTRA(2) = TextData.Text
        ENTRA(3) = TextValor.Text
        ENTRA(4) = TextNota.Text
        itm = New ListViewItem(ENTRA)
        ListViewEntradas.Items.Add(itm)

        'AGORA NO ListTextEntradas...........
        ListTextEntrada.Items.Add(TextDesc.Text)
        ListTextEntrada.Items.Add(TextMes.Text)
        ListTextEntrada.Items.Add(TextData.Text)
        ListTextEntrada.Items.Add(TextValor.Text)
        ListTextEntrada.Items.Add(TextNota.Text)
        ListTextEntrada.Items.Add("__________________________________________________________________")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Erro ao transportar suas digitações para a Lista de Entrada!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Erro: 0Txt:Lst")
    End Try

End Sub
```

A Visualização da Impressão fica assim: (Imprime da mesma forma)

[image]